# Where are the Durandal transitions?

Tags: durandal, transition

Nuget says I already have the Durandal Transitions package installed for the project I'm examining, but `~/Scripts/durandal/transitions` contains only the default transition `entrance.js`

Where are the other transitions? *Are* there other transitions? Creating a new project in a new solution and adding the `Durandal Transitions` NuGet package yields the same result (just `entrance.js`). I can find documentation on how to *create* a transition but no list of extant transitions.

I really just want left and right hand variations on entrance for use with left and right swipes on mobile devices. I'm pretty sure I can do this myself but I find it hard to believe it hasn't already been done.

---

When using Eric's answer, it is important to read the whole page then follow the link to the fork for a [Durandal 2.0 version](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jstott/6326038/raw/2daa2c7cf2b95f159f92826ba224b51195a627f6/transitionHelper.js) because there are profound differences.

As an aside, it is possible to produce context sensitive transitions.

```
define(['durandal/system', 'transitions/helper', 'plugins/router'], 
  function (system, helper, router) {

  return function (context) {
    switch (router.swipe) {
      case "left":
        context.inAnimation = 'slideInRight';
        context.outAnimation = 'slideOutLeft';
        break;
      case "right":
        context.inAnimation = 'slideInLeft';
        context.outAnimation = 'slideOutRight';
        break;
    }
    return helper.create(context);
  };

});
```

As you may have guessed, this depends on the router having a property `swipe` which is maintained by event handlers for swipe events prior to initiating navigation to the adjacent page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Durandal comes prepackaged with the *entrance* transition.  You'll need to do a little bit of work to bring in others (and there are *many* others).

First, you'll want the **transitions helper**, which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/evanlarsen/4799019).

Once you have this file, which you should store under the Scripts folder, in a folder called *durandal*, you then write transitions that reference it.  Here is my **fadeIn** transition, stored in a file named **fadeIn.js** (take note of the anatomy of this code):

```
define(['durandal/system', './transitionHelper'], function(system, helper) {
    var settings = {
            inAnimation: 'fadeIn',
            outAnimation: 'fadeOut'
        },
        fadeIn = function(context) {
            system.extend(context, settings);
            return helper.create(context);
        };

    return fadeIn;
});
```

Notice that my `inAnimation` and my `outAnimation` settings are strings that reference animations stored in the transitions helper file.

Here's another one I write, stored in a file called **fadeInVerticalDown.js**, referencing completely different animations in the transitions helper:

```
define(['durandal/system', './transitionHelper'], function(system, helper) {
    var settings = {
            inAnimation: 'fadeInDownBig',
            outAnimation: 'fadeOutUpBig'
        },
        fadeInVerticalDown = function(context) {
            system.extend(context, settings);
            return helper.create(context);
        };

    return fadeInVerticalDown;
});
```

Take a look at the folder structure below.  Notice that the **transitionHelper.js** file is a sibling of the transitions you write, including of the **entrance.js** file itself.

[image: folder structure]

**UPDATE**

Be sure to read the comment below the transitions helper code that references the **CSS3 Animation Library** and its corresponding **animate.css** file.  You'll need to bring in that file so that the CSS classes added (and removed) by the transitions helper can leverage the animations created for us there.

Comment: This is a damn fine answer. I'm going to accept it, but I hope you'll expand on your statement that there are many transitions by suggesting at least one good place to find them. I rather expected to find at least *some* of them in a package called "Durandal Transitions", the name of which led me to expect more than one.

Comment: @PeterWone  You know, I had the same confusion, not knowing what I was holding in my hand, so to speak.  The transitions are actually there, in the helper.  You're simply writing an adapter that leverages them on the *in* and the *out*.  What you're probably missing, as did I, is that the helper simply leverages the file called **animate.css**, which you can read about in the comment below the source of the helper (I apologize: I forgot to mention that).  You'll need to bring in **animate.css**.

Comment: And bringing in animation.css is exactly what I've been doing while you were writing that. This is *awesome*! Also rather large for nothing but CSS but who cares, it'll sit in cache very nicely. I have the distinct feeling that the whole Durandal transitions mechanism pre-dates CSS3 transitions, and is a bit redundant (and probably absent or differently shaped in Aurelia).

Comment: @PeterWone  And, you know, you can always appropriate from that file what you actually need, and then carve out the rest.  So the file doesn't have to be any larger than what's necessary in the end...

Answer (score 1):

Since this didn't work for me, I'll throw in my two cents. What I did was, after copying animate.css to my css folder and referencing it in my main index.html file, I copied entrance.js found in lib/durandal/js/transitions to slideInLeft.js in the same folder. Then I replaced line 66

```
var entrance = function(context) {
```

with:

```
var slideInLeft = function(context) {
```

And then again line 138

```
return entrance;
```

with:

```
return slideInLeft;
```

Now to change the transition itself. I searched for **entrance-in** and replaced it with **slideInLeft**. Another search for **entrance-out** and replace it with **slideOutRight**. I noticed that there was no transition and the problem was that my div's didn't have the **animated** class. So I added a line after line 98, going from:

```
if (animation) {
    removeAnimationClasses(context.child, fadeOnly);
```

to:

```
if (animation) {
    context.child.classList.add('animated');
    removeAnimationClasses(context.child, fadeOnly);
```

This worked pretty well but I only saw one transition (slideOutRight) and it was very quick; by this I mean I was already seeing the next page before the transition was over. I played around with the duration and settled for a duration of 3000 in line 14:

```
var fadeOutDuration = 3000;
```

Now I was seeing the whole transition, but only one. After a lot of logging to console, I added a line after 103 going from:

```
if(context.activeView){
    removeAnimationClasses(context.activeView, fadeOnly);
}
```

to:

```
if(context.activeView){
    removeAnimationClasses(context.activeView, fadeOnly);
    context.child.classList.add('slideInLeft');
}
```

And that was it. I hope this helps someone.